# batch edit organizations

Tags: batches

I would like to bulk add countries to my organizations via profiles but when adding an organizational field type I can't see the country field, only the official name, SIC code and some custom fields I created. I can only see country at "contact" type  not at "oragnization" tpye. 
But bulk editing organizations with this "contact type profile field" doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please elaborate on what 'But bulk editing organizations with this "contact type profile field" doesn't do anything.' means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the country field to your profile. Since the country field applies to all Contacts it shows under Contacts.

[image]
Make sure you do not have any other conflicting entities in the same profile you are using to batch update orgs.

You should create a profile called 'Batch Update Organization' to be used just to batch update the organization contacts.